# Java exports ANSI file instead of UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, encode, ansi

I'm trying to create a file with FileOutputStream, but it always creates ANSI format like the picture below. I made all character encode settings on Eclipse and IntelliJ, but still same issue.

[image: Character problems on ANSI]

And here is my code:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Student implements Serializable{  
int id;  
 String name;  
 public Student(int id, String name) {  
  this.id = id;  
  this.name = name;  
 }  
}
public class sss {
     public static void main(String args[]){    
          try{    
          //Creating the object    
          Student s1 =new Student(211,"ravi");    
          //Creating stream and writing the object    
          FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("f.txt");    
          ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);    
          out.writeObject(s1);    
          out.flush();    
          //closing the stream    
          out.close();    
          System.out.println("success");    
          }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}    
         }    
    
}
```

Comment: You're writing a binary file, not a text file. `ObjectOutputStream` is for the binary serialization format of Java objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `ObjectOutputStream` there; that is for binary java objects.
Avoid Serializable; it is practicably deprecated. Also Serializable also stores the class data.

```
try (FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("f.txt")) {
    fout.write(s1.name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
} // Closes fout.
```

The "error" might be caused that the latest String class, which will hold Unicode, normally as array of UTF-16 chars, can also hold an ANSI byte array.

Also you hard-code a string (`new Student(211,"ravi");`) which means that the editor saving the java source and the javac compiler must use the same encoding to generate a .class file. When not the string will be corrupted.

```
  try {    
      //Creating the object    
      Student s1 = new Student(212, "Jérome");    
      //Creating stream and writing the object    
      Path path = Paths.get("f.txt");    
      Files.writeString(path, s1.name); // Default UTF-8
      path = path.resolveSibling("f-latin1.txt");    
      Files.writeString(path, s1.name, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
      System.out.println("success");    
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
```

Comment: For your first code block, it would probably be better to use an `OutputStreamWriter` created with the proper character set and using `write(String)`, than manually converting a string to bytes and writing those.

Comment: @Joop Eggen , Thank you for your answer. I learned more in one question :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Student also had an int id, which was not part of the question but of the serialization. So I kept a FileOutputStream. Maybe I should have mentioned a DataOutputStream.